# Why aren't my modules installed via easy_install useable?

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

I recently tried to install a couple of python modules via `easy_install` on my mac.

**Background:**

I'm using OS X 10.6.8 and Python 2.7.2. If I run `which python` I get the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

**Problem:**

If I try to install a package, say `easy_install cssutils` - it finds the package, downloads and says it's installed, but when I then open python and type `import cssutils` - it says the package isn't found.

This has happened with multiple packages, but they do however work if the package has it's own installer script and I run that.

How can I get `easy_install` to install the packages correctly?

Comment: What does `which easy_install` say?

Comment: @birryree `/usr/bin/easy_install`

Comment: Please list all the version of Python and easy_install on your Mac (they're in the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions directory.  Then do `which easy_install` to find the script you ran.  Then open the `easy_install` script to find out what version of Python it's going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Typing:

```
  head -1 `which easy_install`
```

at the command line will show the interpreter that easy_install is using. If it doesn't match the python version you're using, you may need to install setup tools for the version of python you're using. Alternately, if the correct version of easy install is present, you can either run it by using an absolute path, reference the specific easy_install variant (e.g. easy_install-2.7),  or update your path.

Comment: On Mac OS X there's generally a family of easy_install scripts available, each with a unique Python version name.  `easy_install-2.6`, etc.  No change needs to be made; simply use the proper `easy_install` variant.

Comment: That is true, unless python was installed manually. If a manual installation was performed then the correct version of easy_install may not be there.

Comment: I'm referring to building from source, and my own experience in that area.